# Prove that a function from X to R is S-measurable if and only if the function is constant on Ek for every k ∈ Z+.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose X is a set and E1, E2, . . . is a disjoint sequence of subsets of X such that the union of Ek =X. Let S= {UEk : K⊂Z+}. 
(a) Show that S is a σ-algebra on X. 
(b) Prove that a function from X to R is S-measurable if and only if the function is constant on Ek for every k ∈ Z+.

I think I have part a figured out -- as long as I can assume that the empty set is contained in X (which I am not sure I can, since X is not defined).

For part B, I have a proof, but I am not sure it's legit:

First, if F is S measurable, then f^-1((a,infinity)) is an element of S. If we assume that F is NOT constant, then there exists a and b in X such that f(a) > f(b).

Now: f^1((a,infinity))ES 
-> f^1(R(-infinity,a])ES
->X\f(-infinity,a]) ES

This implies that f^-1((-infinity,a]) is not in S, Since (-infnity,a] is a Borel set, this means f can't be S measurable.

Does this work or have I missed something? Somehow I suspect I've made an error in logic, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For your part a question, the empty set is a subset of every set, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot discern well what you do in your answer so decided to give you the opportunity to check yourself.

---

(a)

Let $\mathcal S:=\{\bigcup_{k\in K}E_k\mid K\subseteq\mathbb Z_{>0}\}$ where the $E_k$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ with $X=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}}E_k$.

Then evidently $\mathcal S$ is closed under complements and countable unions so can be classified as a $\sigma$-algebra.

This with $E_k\in\mathcal S$ for every $k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ so that $\sigma(\{E_k\mid k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\})\subseteq\mathcal S$.

Also it is evident that $\mathcal S\subseteq\sigma(\{E_k\mid k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\})$ so we conclude that:$$\mathcal S=\sigma(\{E_k\mid k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\})$$

---

(b)

If a function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is constant on every $E_k$ then for *every* $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ we find that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal S$.

So the function is $\mathcal S$-measurable, no matter with what $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb R$ is equipped.

If conversely $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is not constant on some $E_{k_0}$ and takes two distinct values $u<v$ on that set then $f^{-1}((-\infty,u]))$ cannot be an element of $\mathcal S$.

This because its intersection with $E_{k_0}$ is not empty but we do not have $E_{k_0}\subseteq f^{-1}((-\infty,u]))$.

This proves that $f$ is not $\mathcal S$-measurable.

Comment: Can you please explain the first line further? Suppose I look at only open sets, let one be $B$, then how can I be sure that $f^{−1}(B) \in S$? It's intuitively easier to understand  that any countable set $B$ will satisfy this, but hard for me to understand with open sets.

Comment: @ali For every $x$ there is a unique positive integer $k_x$ with $x\in E_{k_x}$. Further $f$ is constant on $E_{k_x}$, so if $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ then we will have $f(y)=f(x)\in B$ for every $y\in K_x$ or equivalently $E_{k_x}\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.  This works for every $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ so that we have found:$$f^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}(B)}E_{k_x}$$showing directly that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: In your first comment, I think it should be $f(y)=f(x) \in B.$ Otherwise, it makes total sense!

Comment: @ali You are right, and I was just in time to repair it.

Comment: For the second part, (I'm checking if I understand) we can be sure that $f^{−1}((−\inf ,u]))  cannot be an element of S$, since the $f^{−1}((−\inf ,u]))$ has to be a union of some $E_k'$s, and if that union intersects with set $E_{k0}$, we get a contradiction. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ali Yes, that is correct understanding. It is a matter of all or nothing. $E_{k_0}$ must have empty intersection or must be a subset. You are welcome.